# Rendering without WebGL

Tags: canvas, webgl, processing, processing.js

Can we do this with Processing.js?

We've built a system rendering in P3D that sketches simple boxes and text with some camera movements.

We need to get this to work in browsers without WebGL. It's simple enough not to require high frame rates, texture maps or WebGL's GPU acceleration.

How would you suggest we do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P3D and OpenGL mode use webgl in Processing.js, so: no, if you're using anything from the 3D API, Processing.js will be rendering that using a WebGL context (because Canvas2D has no pseudo-3D functions, and implementing them in Pjs would be an incredible amount of work, while also being very slow =)